# sonar check the configuration at https://analysis.apache/system

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I did a fresh installation of java, sonar, maven, mysql on my windows box.

I have also managed to update the sonar conf to use the mysql database.

Sonar starts smooth, and I could access localhost:9000.

However, when I try to execute mvn install sonar:sonar on a freshly checked out apache-commons project, the build fails with ERROR

ERROR - The current bath process and the configured remote server do not share the same DB configuration.
ERROR - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar (root / ****)
ERROR - Server side: check the configuration at https:/analysis.apache.org/system

I confirm that the user name and password are correct. However, the server side URL is somehow pointing to https://analysis.apache.org/system, where I believe it should be pointing to my local box.

Also, there were few blogs suggesting to check the server ID in the sonar database vs the server ID from sonar server. Here I see the value "20150423155830" by executing SELECT text_value FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'sonar.core.id';

However, not sure where to check for the sonar server "server ID". I assumed it to be http:/localhost:9000/system, but I don't see any value for "Server ID" under System Info! Is it related? I also tried "generating" a new server ID on the admin dashboard, but did not resolve the issue.

Please shed some light. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache SonarQube isntance (analysis.apache.org) is declared in the root pom file of Commons projects: see property sonar.host.url in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/commons-parent/trunk/pom.xml. 
The solution is to override this property in command-line (mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<...>)